# Double Encoding on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, encoding

[image]

So yeah, on the list of merges on the [Sports proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports), "Snowboard and Ski" is showing as "Snowboard `&amp;` Ski."

Comment: +1 for the [encoding-fail] tag. But where's the [questions-appears-empty-in-list] tag?

Comment: Bugs for Area 51 should be reported on discussion.area51.stackexchage.com, using "area51-meta" as tag.

Comment: Area 51 bugs actually *do* belong here on Meta (yes, we realize this is a bit confusing). [Area 51 Discussion](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/) is for talking about the proposals themselves, and not so much for pointing out bugs in the software.

Comment: @Emmett Robert Cartaino removed the reference to the Meta Stack Overflow being the meta for Area 51, from the Meta Stack Overflow's FAQ. I get that if the bug is about code running exclusively on Area 51, the bug should be reported there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kk fine, we'll only encode that once – it's fixed now.